# How can I change a section's title color by editing the template in iBooks Author?

Tags: mac, customization, ibooks-author, template

I'm trying to make a book with iBooks Author on my Mac by customizing the "Contemporary" template. When I switch the view mode from landscape to  portrait, the section title color is red - I want it green!

Since I can edit the section title in landscape mode I can't understand why I'm not able to edit its color as well.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The layouts easily editable when using the graphical interface of iBooks Author.

Close any documents you may have open to avoid confusion and then open a new document from the template chooser. Start with a template you like and …

- **View** menu -> **Show Layouts**
- make your changes to fonts, colors, layout, etc… on each type of page, working your way down the list.
- **File** menu -> **Save as Template…**

At that point, save it in the default location and when you start a new document, you can choose your custom layout for starting a new book.